# Get schema of an element of the transformed array in `zod`

Tags: typescript, zod

I have a schema for an object retrieved from back-end. Since the names of the fields in the back-end don't match the naming convention in my front-end, I transform the data and simplify its structure a bit, so I get an array. From this array I can easily infer a type.
In the documentation I see that it should be possible to use `.element` to access the schema for an element of the array. However, this is not possible and I assume that the reason is that the array is a result of a transformation. If I create an array schema directly, I can do it.

```js
const oZodBackendData = z
  .object({
    results: z.array(
      z.object({
        attr: z.string(),
      })
    ),
  })
  .readonly();

export const oZodData = oZodBackendData 
  .transform((oBackendData) =>
    oBackendData.results.map((oBackendDataElement) => ({
      otherName: oBackendDataElement.attr,
    }))
  )
  .readonly();

export type Data = z.infer<typeof oZodData>;

oZodData.element // Property 'element' does not exist on type ...
```

Is there an easy solution to this problem?

Comment: Your Zod transform operation changes ```oZodData``` into an array of objects. But when you are trying to access data from ```oZodData``` you are not trying to access data from an array, but an object.

Comment: Question not clear to me. Are you trying to get the type of an individual element of the transformed Zod array? Or are you trying to extract an section of the validation schema?

Comment: @Zxeenu As input from back-end I have an object with single `results` property which contains an array. I want to simplify this structure, so I make it an array that can be accessed directly. When transforming, I access the data from this array (in `results` property) and at the same time rename properties of elements: `oBackendData.results.map(...)`.  
As a result, I want to get a schema of a single element of an array that has been transformed from the input object and is represented by `oZodData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zod's `transform` method doesn't change your original schema. The `transform` method only chains an additional method onto your validator.

Because the method doesn't change your original schema to an array validation schema, you don't have access to the `element` property that Zod's array validation schemas have.

Comment: It would be quite useful tho.